# Filtering Negative Balance in a MS Access Query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created a hotel booking database that has a payment query where I have total cost field, total paid field and balance field but I can seem to filter those whose balance is greater than total paid. I need to create a debtors report based on bookings.

SQL statement of the query I intend to sort debtors:

```vb
SELECT "Print" AS Print, "Make Payment" AS MakePayment, tblBookingPayments.BookingPaymentID, tblBookings.GuestID_FK, 
tblBookingPayments.Discount, CCur(DSum("[Amount]","qryCostsPaymentsUnion",
"[BookingID]=" & [BookingID] & " AND [Item]<>'" & "Payment" & "'")-([Discount])) AS TotalCost, 
CCur(DSum("[Amount]","qryCostsPaymentsUnion",
"[BookingID]=" & [BookingID] & " AND [Item]='" & "Payment" & "'")) AS TotalPaid, CCur([TotalPaid]-[TotalCost]) AS Balance, 
tblBookings.BookingID, tblBookingPayments.EmployeeID, tblBookingDetails.CheckInDate, 
tblBookingDetails.CheckOutDate
FROM (tblBookings INNER JOIN tblBookingDetails ON tblBookings.BookingID = tblBookingDetails.BookingID_FK) INNER JOIN 
tblBookingPayments ON tblBookings.BookingID = tblBookingPayments.BookingID_FK;
```

Comment: You do not have any WHERE clause there so it cannot filter anything.

Comment: Can't use aggregate calcs in WHERE clause of same query. Use HAVING clause. Access query designer should construct this. Or apply filter with WHERE argument of OpenReport command.